# What is the best way to deal with optional delegates in a c# constructor?

Tags: c#, delegates, constructor-chaining

I'm refactoring a function that takes in an optional delegate through the constructor. The delegate is run when events are triggered within the class. If the delegate isn't passed then a local default function is used instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    int    _memberVariable;
    readonly Action _onEventOne;
    readonly Action _onEventTwo;

    public Foo(Action onEventOne, Action onEventTwo = null)
    {
        _memberVariable = 0;

        _onEventOne = onEventOne;
        _onEventTwo = onEventTwo ?? DefaultEventTwo;

        _onEventOne();
    }

    private void DefaultEventTwo()
    {
        ++_memberVariable;
    }
}
```

I'm looking to remove the default value (this is a public interface so overloading would be preferable), and this is in production code so I don't want to change the interface unless I must.

In an ideal world I'd use constructor chaining:

```
public Foo(Action onEventOne) : this(onEventOne, DefaultEventTwo)
{
    //CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Foo.DefaultEventTwo()
}
```

(I understand why this doesn't work, just giving an example of the kind of solution I would use if this weren't a constructor).

Because the delegates are readonly I can't set them in a shared initialize type function.

Is there a better way to handle a case like than just passing in null and then catching it in the main constructor? It doesn't feel very elegant, and I'd like to be able to catch a null Action as an exception ideally (for if an external caller used null instead of using the overloaded constructor). I could remove the readonly from the delegates but again it doesn't feel like a great solution as they are really readonly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: public `Foo(Action onEventOne) : this(onEventOne, null)` would be a way or  `public Foo(Action onEventOne) : this(onEventOne, new Action(Console.Beep))` or you have a func like: `public static void NoEvent()
    {
        // DoNothing()
    }` and handle it like: `...,new Action(NoEvent)`

Comment: And then you simply check for `null` and if it passes call `DefaultEventTwo` instead of the (not) provided delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this working was by getting it working ugly (in my own opinion).

You have to deliver a static method, but that static method could use a reference to this to get the actual method out.

This is what I came up with.

```
public Foo(Action onEventOne) : this(onEventOne, self => self.DefaultEventTwo)
{
    //CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Foo.DefaultEventTwo()
}

public Foo(Action onEventOne, Action onEventTwo = null) : this(onEventOne, self => onEventTwo)
{ }

// private constructor, just for the sake of getting it working
private Foo(Action onEventOne, Func<Foo, Action> onEventTwo = null)
{
    _memberVariable = 0;

    _onEventOne = onEventOne;
    _onEventTwo = onEventTwo(this); // <--

    _onEventOne();
}
```

`self => self.DefaultEventTwo` is the static function to get the action. That function is used in the call to `onEventTwo(this)` to get the default event of `this` instance.

Comment: I suspect there is not going to be any truly nice solution to this, I am mostly interested to see what ideas people had and this is certainly the most interesting so far. This is definitely works well for the problem as stated, but starts to get a little confusing if you add extra optional events (obviously not a mark against it here, but just a point worth noting if anyone else happens across this in future).

Comment: Yeah, it is just not possible to do what you want without making it static or moving it into the constructor as in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did I miss anything?

```
public class Foo
{
    int    _memberVariable;
    readonly Action _onEventOne;
    readonly Action _onEventTwo;

    public Foo(Action onEventOne): this(onEventOne, null) { }
    public Foo(Action onEventOne, Action onEventTwo)
    {
        _memberVariable = 0;

        _onEventOne = onEventOne;
        _onEventTwo = onEventTwo ?? DefaultEventTwo;

        _onEventOne();
    }

    private void DefaultEventTwo()
    {
        ++_memberVariable;
    }
}
```

All you have to do is delete the default-value and create a new constructor which has only one argument. Now in the most detailed constructor (the original one) check if the provided value is `null` and if so set `_onEventTwo` to `DefaultEventTwo`.

To avoid that anyone uses the reduced constructor simply make it `internal`.

EDIT: Concerning the exception-handling. What about using an internal constructor as "main"-one that all the others call with a param indicating where the call came from:

```
internal Foo(Action onEventOne): this(onEventOne, null, true) { }
// public API: NULL not allwoed as param
public Foo(Action onEventOne, Action onEventTwo) : this(onEventOne, onEventTwo, false) { }
internal Foo(Action onEventOne, Action onEventTwo, bool internalUse)
{
    _memberVariable = 0;

    _onEventOne = onEventOne;
    if(onEventTwo == null)
    {
        if(!internalUse) throw new ArgumentNullException("onEventTwo");
        else this._onEventTwo = DefaultEventTwo;
    }
    _onEventOne();
}
```

Comment: I think you second solution fits the question much better of the two (I might have worded the question confusingly - your first solution was what I first did but I am looking for alternatives). Adding an extra argument is an interesting idea I hadn't even considered (seems so obvious now), thanks!